# Python Order Alphabetically without preceding zeros for numbers less than 10

Tags: python

I would like to list a directory with Python. My directory only has files with name :

```
A1, A2, A3,..., A10, A11,..., B1,B2, ..., B10, B11 ...
```

Problem is that when I try with alphabetically order it with Python :

```
listQuery = os.listdir('C:\\query\\')
listQuery.sort()
```

I got the following order :

```
A1, A10, A11, ... ,A2 ...
```

So my question is how can I first alphabetically order those and then order it with numbers

Comment: This is often called "natural sorting": see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4836734/1222578) for a simple Python implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a sorting key function, like:

```
def my_order(value):
    return (value[0], int(value[1:]))
```

Then use it to sort your list:

```
listQuery.sort(key=my_order)
```

This calls the `my_order` function on every value in the list, then sorts the list based on those newly computed values. This is also known as a "decorate-sort-undecorate" ("DSU") or "Schwartzian transform".

In this case, it creates a list of tuples like `('A', 2)`, `('A', 11)`, etc. Python sorts tuples based on their individual values. If two tuples have the same first value (like `'A'`), it moves on to the next pair of values (`2` and `11` here). Since both of those are integers, it would sort them numerically. It uses that ordering to sort the original list.